# PostMan not returning accurate result

Tags: google-chrome, post, postman, soapui

I have created a web service on a website Let us say "A" .This A has security login to enter into the website (SSO).When i hit the url of the webservice ( which is part of A ) from postman.This is returning the SSO login page html code.For this particular web service i don't have any authentication.so i didn't specify any authentication in Postman.I noticed that when i hit the web service from browser it is getting the result.I want to Post something to webservice and test.

Do i have any other option in the browser itself to post a json ? ( i tried postman chrome extension not worked)

any thing that could resolve the above issue is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to post something to an API (your webservice). The first thing to check here is - does you API has a POST method implementation? 
If yes, then follow the steps:

1. In your Postman App, choose POST instead of GET.
2. Click on "Body" from the below tabs.
3. Click on "raw" and from the drop-down choose JSON(application/json).
4. Hit send.

Based on your API request and implementation you should be getting the response.

P.S. the question is ambiguous, my answer assumes that OP is asking how to make a POST call in postman.

[image: How to make a post api call in POSTMAN]